# Is $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{R}$ countable or uncountable?

Tags: real-analysis

**Problem:**

> Is $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{R}$ countable or uncountable?

**Attempt:**
It's known that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, and $ \# \mathbb{R} = \#(0,1)$ is uncountable. I then use the fact that:
$$\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{R}=\bigcup_{x \in (0,1)}(\mathbb{Q} \times \{x\})>\mathbb{N\times N}$$
which shows that $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{R}$ is uncountable.

Am i on the right track?

Comment: Why not take the union as $\cup_{q\in\mathbb{Q}}(\{q\}\times\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Are you claiming that $\mathbb{N\times N}$ is uncountable? If so, what is your justification?

Comment: All you need is a surjection to $\mathbb R$, for example $(q,r)\mapsto r$

Comment: I'm pretty sure that $\mathbb{N \times N}$ is countable, and if $\mathbb{Q times R} >\mathbb{N \times N}$ then $\mathbb{Q \times R}$ is uncountable.

Comment: Be careful with your notation as well.  You claim "$\Bbb Q\times \Bbb R = \dots$".  Here, this would read as *the set* on the left is equal *as a set* to the set on the right.  You mean to be talking about the *cardinality of the set* on the left being equal *as a cardinality* to the cardinality of the set on the right.  These are two very different statements.

Comment: I think i got a good idea by looking at:

$(\bigcup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}}\{q\}) \times \mathbb{R}=\bigcup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}}(\{q\} \times \mathbb{R})$

Comment: Were $\Bbb Q\times\Bbb R$ countable, then the subset $\{0\}\times\Bbb R\cong\Bbb R$ would be countable

Comment: I don't exactly understand which fact you're using to claim that $\bigcup_{x\in (0,1)}(\Bbb Q\times \{x\})>\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$.

Comment: Well, (0,1) and  $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable, right? And by the definition in our book:

"If #$\mathbb{N}<$#X then the set X is said to be uncountable."

By another example in our book it's known that $\mathbb{N \times N}$ is countable, so if $\mathbb{Q \times R} >\mathbb{N \times N}$ then \mathbb{Q \times R}  is said to be uncountable.

Comment: @Flems I still don't understand. Is $\bigcup_{x\in (0,1)}(\Bbb Q\times\{x\})>\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ a theorem you have proved? If so, how?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio No, to be honest i just thought it made a lot of sense, given that $(0,1)$ is uncountable.

Comment: By $>$, I assume you mean cardinality is strictly greater? If so, how do you justify that step?

Comment: @gst076923 That's correct. I guess one would usually do it by bijection or injection, but in this case i think it's pretty hard to construct a function as a counter example.

Comment: You are right that the inequality you wrote makes sense. And while that inequality might guide you to a proof, you should recognize that simply asserting the truth of that inequality is not, in-and-of itself, a proof.

Comment: is there a rule like cartesian product of countable  and uncountable is uncountable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your definition of (un)countable, this could be simplified.

Definition: A set $S$ is said to be uncountable if there exists a surjective map $f:S\longrightarrow\Bbb{R}$ (or any other uncountable set you desire).

---

To show that $\Bbb{Q}\times\Bbb{R}$ is uncountable, consider $f:\Bbb{Q}\times\Bbb{R} \longrightarrow \Bbb{R}$ where $(a,\alpha)\mapsto \alpha.$ It is clear that $f$ is well defined. To show it is surjective, let $\beta \in \Bbb{R}.$ Then any element $(b,\beta)\in \Bbb{Q}\times\Bbb{R}$ has the property that $f(b,\beta)=\beta.$ Thus, $f$ is surjective. Since $f: \Bbb{Q}\times\Bbb{R} \longrightarrow \Bbb{R}$ is surjective, then $\Bbb{Q}\times\Bbb{R}$ must bet uncountable.

Answer (score 4):

Note that
$$\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{R} \supseteq \{0\}\times\mathbb{R} \cong \mathbb{R}$$

Since $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable, so must $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{R}$

Comment: is there a rule like cartesian product of countable and uncountable is uncountable? if so then is that rule proven exactly by something like what you've said? I think if $A$ is countable and $B$ isn't then just do $A \times B \supseteq \{a\} \times B$ ?

Answer (score 1):

You were almost on the right track to prove the statement easily (you can proceed by your method, but it requires some more work to complete it).

Observe that $$\mathbb Q\times \mathbb R=\bigcup_{q\in\mathbb Q}(\{q\}\times\mathbb R)$$ Now suppose there exists a bijection $\phi$ between $\mathbb Q\times\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb N$.

Pick up one of the sets in the union, say $\{0\}\times\mathbb R=:A$. Then $A\subset \mathbb Q\times\mathbb R$ and is clearly in bijection with $\mathbb R$ say by $\psi$). Then $A$ is in bijection with $\phi(A)\subseteq \mathbb N$. Compose this with $\psi$ (or $\psi^{-1}$ as per your definition), and you get a bijection between a subset (proper or improper doesn't matter) of $\mathbb N$ with $\mathbb R$, which is impossible.

Thus there exists no bijection between $\mathbb Q\times\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb N$ and hence the former set is uncountable.

Answer (score 0):

Cartesian product of countable and uncountable is uncountable.

Proof: If $A$ is countable and $B$ isn't, then

$$A \times B \supseteq \{a\} \times B$$ QED

---

Btw, [Cartesian Product of Countable Sets is Countable](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cartesian_Product_of_Countable_Sets_is_Countable).